# Xpath for Gmail encountering issue

Tags: xpath

I'm investigating automation task relating to Gmail using non-US language.

I've 2 parent labels ('Cá nhân', Cá thể) and 3 sub-labels, they're on the left panel of Gmail:

Cá nhân

- Private
- Remotekit

Cá thể

- Cá tính

Installing Xpath Helper extension in Chrome Browser. Then, open it to identify the 'Cá nhân' location

```
//div[@class='aio aip']//a[contains(string(),'C')]
```

--> Result returns 4: 'Cá nhân,Cá thể,Cá tính,Cơ quan'

Then, I type full:

```
//div[@class='aio aip']//a[contains(string(),'Cá nhân')]
```

--> Result return: Null

But, if I type `//div[@class='aio aip']//a[contains(string(),'Ca')]`

--> Result return: 'Cá nhân'

Why does have difference result between short name 'Ca' and full name 'Cá nhân' -- is this UTF8 encoding ?

One strange, if `//div[@class='aio aip']//a[contains(string(),'Cá thể')]`, it can find exactly 'Cá thể' label location

Please help me figure out the issue.

Comment: First of all you don't need XPath helper in Chrome. You can use `$x("your xpath here")` in the console. Second, yes this seems to be an encoding issue. Try to copy the texts directly from the page.

Comment: @Artjom, how to fix this encoding issue ? Thanks,

Comment: I tried it with the language Tiếng Việt in the gmail settings and I had no problems selecting elements. Are you sure you copy the text directly from the page or elements tab of the dev tools?

Comment: @Artjom: Yes, I copied directly from source.